Py4JJavaError in Jupyter notebook
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession  
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("PySpark create using parallelize() function RDD example").config("spark.some.config.option", "some-value").getOrCreate()  
df = spark.sparkContext.parallelize([(12, 20, 35, 'a b c'),  
(41, 58, 64, 'd e f'),  
(70, 85, 90, 'g h i')]).toDF(['col1', 'col2', 'col3','col4'])  
df.show()

I am trying to create a RDD using parallelize() and createDataFrame() function
but I am encountering with the error. Using jupyter notebook through anaconda prompt
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[13], line 5
      1 from pyspark.sql import SparkSession  
      2 spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("PySpark create using parallelize() function RDD example").config("spark.some.config.option", "some-value").getOrCreate()  
      3 df = spark.sparkContext.parallelize([(12, 20, 35, 'a b c'),  
      4 (41, 58, 64, 'd e f'),  
----> 5 (70, 85, 90, 'g h i')]).toDF(['col1', 'col2', 'col3','col4'])  
      6 df.show()

File C:\Spark\sparkhome\python\pyspark\sql\session.py:122, in _monkey_patch_RDD.<locals>.toDF(self, schema, sampleRatio)
     87 @no_type_check
     88 def toDF(self, schema=None, sampleRatio=None):
     89     """
     90     Converts current :class:`RDD` into a :class:`DataFrame`
     91 
   (...)
    120     +---+
    121     """
--> 122     return sparkSession.createDataFrame(self, schema, sampleRatio)

File C:\Spark\sparkhome\python\pyspark\sql\session.py:1443, in SparkSession.createDataFrame(self, data, schema, samplingRatio, verifySchema)
   1438 if has_pandas and isinstance(data, pd.DataFrame):
   1439     # Create a DataFrame from pandas DataFrame.
   1440     return super(SparkSession, self).createDataFrame(  # type: ignore[call-overload]
   1441         data, schema, samplingRatio, verifySchema
   1442     )
-> 1443 return self._create_dataframe(
   1444     data, schema, samplingRatio, verifySchema  # type: ignore[arg-type]
   1445 )

File C:\Spark\sparkhome\python\pyspark\sql\session.py:1483, in SparkSession._create_dataframe(self, data, schema, samplingRatio, verifySchema)
   1480         return obj
   1482 if isinstance(data, RDD):
-> 1483     rdd, struct = self._createFromRDD(data.map(prepare), schema, samplingRatio)
   1484 else:
   1485     rdd, struct = self._createFromLocal(map(prepare, data), schema)

File C:\Spark\sparkhome\python\pyspark\sql\session.py:1056, in SparkSession._createFromRDD(self, rdd, schema, samplingRatio)
   1052 """
   1053 Create an RDD for DataFrame from an existing RDD, returns the RDD and schema.
   1054 """
   1055 if schema is None or isinstance(schema, (list, tuple)):
-> 1056     struct = self._inferSchema(rdd, samplingRatio, names=schema)
   1057     converter = _create_converter(struct)
   1058     tupled_rdd = rdd.map(converter)

File C:\Spark\sparkhome\python\pyspark\sql\session.py:996, in SparkSession._inferSchema(self, rdd, samplingRatio, names)
    975 def _inferSchema(
    976     self,
    977     rdd: RDD[Any],
    978     samplingRatio: Optional[float] = None,
    979     names: Optional[List[str]] = None,
    980 ) -> StructType:
    981     """
    982     Infer schema from an RDD of Row, dict, or tuple.
    983 
   (...)
    994     :class:`pyspark.sql.types.StructType`
    995     """
--> 996     first = rdd.first()
    997     if isinstance(first, Sized) and len(first) == 0:
    998         raise PySparkValueError(
    999             error_class="CANNOT_INFER_EMPTY_SCHEMA",
   1000             message_parameters={},
   1001         )

File C:\Spark\sparkhome\python\pyspark\rdd.py:2888, in RDD.first(self)
   2862 def first(self: "RDD[T]") -> T:
   2863     """
   2864     Return the first element in this RDD.
   2865 
   (...)
   2886     ValueError: RDD is empty
   2887     """
-> 2888     rs = self.take(1)
   2889     if rs:
   2890         return rs[0]

File C:\Spark\sparkhome\python\pyspark\rdd.py:2855, in RDD.take(self, num)
   2852         taken += 1
   2854 p = range(partsScanned, min(partsScanned + numPartsToTry, totalParts))
-> 2855 res = self.context.runJob(self, takeUpToNumLeft, p)
   2857 items += res
   2858 partsScanned += numPartsToTry

File C:\Spark\sparkhome\python\pyspark\context.py:2510, in SparkContext.runJob(self, rdd, partitionFunc, partitions, allowLocal)
   2508 mappedRDD = rdd.mapPartitions(partitionFunc)
   2509 assert self._jvm is not None
-> 2510 sock_info = self._jvm.PythonRDD.runJob(self._jsc.sc(), mappedRDD._jrdd, partitions)
   2511 return list(_load_from_socket(sock_info, mappedRDD._jrdd_deserializer))

File C:\Spark\sparkhome\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9.7-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py:1322, in JavaMember.__call__(self, *args)
   1316 command = proto.CALL_COMMAND_NAME +\
   1317     self.command_header +\
   1318     args_command +\
   1319     proto.END_COMMAND_PART
   1321 answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
-> 1322 return_value = get_return_value(
   1323     answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1325 for temp_arg in temp_args:
   1326     if hasattr(temp_arg, "_detach"):

File C:\Spark\sparkhome\python\pyspark\errors\exceptions\captured.py:179, in capture_sql_exception.<locals>.deco(*a, **kw)
    177 def deco(*a: Any, **kw: Any) -> Any:
    178     try:
--> 179         return f(*a, **kw)
    180     except Py4JJavaError as e:
    181         converted = convert_exception(e.java_exception)

File C:\Spark\sparkhome\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9.7-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py:326, in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    324 value = OUTPUT_CONVERTER[type](answer[2:], gateway_client)
    325 if answer[1] == REFERENCE_TYPE:
--> 326     raise Py4JJavaError(
    327         "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
    328         format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329 else:
    330     raise Py4JError(
    331         "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}. Trace:\n{3}\n".
    332         format(target_id, ".", name, value))

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.runJob.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 2.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 2) (192.168.1.108 executor driver): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker exited unexpectedly (crashed)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(PythonRunner.scala:612)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(PythonRunner.scala:594)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:789)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:766)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:525)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:943)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:943)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.foreach(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
    at scala.collection.generic.Growable.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.generic.Growable.$plus$plus$eq$(Growable.scala:53)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:105)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.to(TraversableOnce.scala:366)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.to$(TraversableOnce.scala:364)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.to(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:358)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toBuffer$(TraversableOnce.scala:358)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.toBuffer(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:345)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toArray$(TraversableOnce.scala:339)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.toArray(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.$anonfun$runJob$1(PythonRDD.scala:181)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.$anonfun$runJob$5(SparkContext.scala:2433)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:93)
    at org.apache.spark.TaskContext.runTaskWithListeners(TaskContext.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:141)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$4(Executor.scala:620)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally(SparkErrorUtils.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally$(SparkErrorUtils.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:94)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:623)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1570)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
    at java.base/java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:210)
    at java.base/java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:385)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:774)
    ... 32 more

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2856)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2792)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2791)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2791)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1247)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1247)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1247)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:3060)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2994)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2983)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:989)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2393)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2414)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2433)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.runJob(PythonRDD.scala:181)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.runJob(PythonRDD.scala)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:374)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1570)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker exited unexpectedly (crashed)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(PythonRunner.scala:612)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(PythonRunner.scala:594)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:789)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:766)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:525)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:943)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:943)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.foreach(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
    at scala.collection.generic.Growable.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.generic.Growable.$plus$plus$eq$(Growable.scala:53)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:105)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.to(TraversableOnce.scala:366)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.to$(TraversableOnce.scala:364)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.to(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:358)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toBuffer$(TraversableOnce.scala:358)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.toBuffer(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:345)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toArray$(TraversableOnce.scala:339)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.toArray(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.$anonfun$runJob$1(PythonRDD.scala:181)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.$anonfun$runJob$5(SparkContext.scala:2433)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:93)
    at org.apache.spark.TaskContext.runTaskWithListeners(TaskContext.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:141)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$4(Executor.scala:620)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally(SparkErrorUtils.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally$(SparkErrorUtils.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:94)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:623)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
    at java.base/java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:210)
    at java.base/java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:385)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:774)
    ... 32 more

I checked my pyspark and python compatibility
my pyspark is 3.5.3 and python is 3.12, java is 22.0.2
My environment variables are all set. Tried by increasing memory in spark session.
also used findspark.init() before spark session.
Still facing this issue I hope for a complete solution for this
